# Употребление аббревиатуры ИМХО

Tags: лексика

Подскажите, пожалуйста, "ИМХО" - это расписка в собственном неведении или заявка на личное мнение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Имхо - от английского  (in my humble opinion» — по моему скромному мнению)

Вот достаточно полное изложения всех оттенков смысла.

> Что такое ИМХО
>
> ИМХО (имхо, Имхо) – часто встречающееся в форумах и
>   Интернет-конференциях словечко, вызывающее замешательство и смутные
>   ассоциации у неподготовленного пользователя. На самом деле ИМХО – это
>   записанная русскими буквами английская аббревиатура IMHO, которая
>   расшифровывается фразой «In my humble opinion» - «По моему скромному
>   мнению» . Набрать на клавиатуре «ИМХО» проще, чем «я думаю» или «я
>   считаю» ; здесь и кроется секрет популярности этого слова. Между тем,
>   великий и могучий русский язык уже давно позволил пользователям Рунета
>   расшифровать «ИМХО» по-своему: «Имею мнение – хрен оспоришь» .
>   Возможно, так оно и правильнее… (ИМХО. )
>
> Но славный путь этого слова на этом не кончается. «Имхо» уже успело
>   стать существительным, которое обычно означает «личное мнение» ,
>   «представление, взгляд, убеждение» или «предположение» .
>
> Чуть реже можно столкнуться с другим значением «имхо» : компьютерный
>   акроним. Т. е. «имхо» – синоним самого определения «акроним,
>   аббревиатура» , родовое слово для всех сокращений такого типа. Что
>   такое «BTB»? Ответ: by the way – «между прочим» , т. е. акроним.
>   Аббревиатура. Ещё одно имхо из множества имх.
>
> Ударение стоит на втором слоге, существительное «имхо» относится к
>   среднему роду и свободно склоняется («без имха» , «по имху») . Имеется
>   и множественное число – «имхи» . В составе сложных слов этот компонент
>   почти не наблюдается: ещё не додумались любители экспериментов назвать
>   референдум или опрос-голосовалку – «имхомером» или «имхометром» . Зато
>   уже есть «имхоизм» . Новое философское течение, не иначе. В онлайновых
>   спорах так и мелькают прилагательные «имхошный» и «имховый» –
>   «субъективный» , «личный» , «основанный на собственном опыте» . Надо
>   заметить, эпитеты эти не лишены самоуверенности и апломба (обратите
>   внимание, как далеко мы ушли от первоначально скромного английского
>   I.M.H.O.). А «имхошник» , наверное, будет человек себе на уме,
>   спорщик, которого трудно переубедить. И наконец, компьютерные пираты,
>   трудясь в своих мрачных берлогах над взломом очередного мегапортала
>   или суперигрушки, машинально мурлыкают под нос: «Имхо-хо и бутылка
>   рома...» . «Имхо-хо» при этом – междометие.
>
> Наряду с правильным литературным вариантом «имхо» употребляется
>   разговорная «имха» (существительное) . Реже попадается неизменяемая
>   форма «имху» (вводное слово) , явно редуцированная из выражения «по
>   моему скромному имху» .
>
> Нельзя признать «имхо» исключительно атрибутом письменной речи.
>   Доводилось слышать, как люди употребляют его в разговоре (опять-таки
>   как вводное слово) . Более того, на наших глазах некий заклятый
>   фидошник «инфицировал» этим «имхом» собеседницу, у которой не имелось
>   не то что доступа к сетям-паутинам, но и вообще персонального
>   компьютера.

[**Что такое имхо? Ответы Mail.Ru**](https://otvet.mail.ru/question/29721040)

Даю полностью, ибо все по теме, хотя не со всем можно согласиться.

В отношении "humble" - не заостряйте, это обычная для английского формула вежливости, англичанина вообще скромность украшает, но тут скромное=частное, поэтому сокращать до ИМО смысла не никакого, я тут не согласен.

Но вопрос-то, судя по формулировке и вашему комментарию, у вас другой. 
О грамматической и стилистической роли этого самого "имхо". По переводу и по смыслу это - вводное сочетание, не случайно его часто оформляют как обособленное.

Но возможно и иное использование, самое разное. От существительного-подлежащего ("Моё имхо") до наречия. Вот там надо смотреть за смыслом. 
"Он имхо передел" - вот шут его знает, что автор хотел сказать. То ли что переделал, то ли как, то ли это говорящий думает, что переделал. 
В первом случае "имхо" = "мнение", во втором "имхо" = "по своему разумению", в третьем имхо = "кажется", "вроде бы". Не угадаешь, лучше такое не использовать.

Ссылки найти очень сложно, само слово далеко от нормативности, но без конкретной фразы не понятно даже, что именно искать.

Answer (score 5):

ИМХО  (in my humble opinion» — по моему скромному мнению) означает, что сказанное мной — **это мое собственное мнение, моё видение проблемы, без ссылок на авторитетные источники**. Это  моё выражение уважения и к себе, и к моим собеседникам, для которых такая информация может быть важной.

По современному значению этого слова  скорее подошла бы аббревиатура ИМО  «in my  opinion».

Comment: Получается, "humble" можно безболезненно выкинуть из фразы, но тогда вся её стилистика рушится.

Comment: @glyptus - о какой фразе речь? Имхо - в русском вообще исключительно разговорное, даже нарочито просторечное. Но меня заинтересовало, из каких слов Sibylla вы сделали такое заключение?

Comment: Да составляю на досуге своего рода паразитарий: "за что купил, за то и продаю", "гугл в помощь, отцепись" и тому подобное. Вот и имхо этому там местечко нашлось.